# Calling Web API endpoint from WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to call a Web API endpoint from my WCF service, here's the code;

```
private static async Task RunAsync(string message)
    {
        var model = new MyModel   
        {
            Message = message
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/RecordMessage", model);
        }
    }
```

What I get return as response is '404'. I get to post the message from a console application, but I couldn't manage to make it work to run it in my WCF service. I tried setting Expect100Continue to true but it seems like that's not the case.

My WCF is hosted in IIS.Has anyone experienced the same issue ?

Comment: Where is your Web API hosted? You mentioned that your WCF service is hosted in IIS but what about the endpoint you are calling?

Comment: it's hosted in IIS as well

Comment: On port 80, the same as your WCF application?

Comment: No, WCF uses https:443. But web API is using 80.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to POST to the `/api/RecordMessage` endpoint. If you are using the default routes configuration:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This means that you must have a controller named `RecordMessageController` containing a method called `Post`:

```
public class RecordMessageController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        ... That's the action that will be invoked when you call
        ... POST /api/RecordMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: I get to post the message from a console application, but I couldn't manage to make it work to run it in my WCF service, so there's no problem about the controller.

Comment: If you used the same client code in your console application then there's no reason for it not working in a WCF application. There's nothing special in the nature of WCF that would make your request fail with 404.

Comment: Here's what I may suggest you for further debugging this issue: you can enable tracing in your console application and capture the exact HTTP request being sent. Then do the same in your WCF application and compare the results and see how they differ.

Comment: They seem to be same as well, I was thinking if there's a setting on IIS I miss out.

Comment: If you make 2 identical requests it doesn't really matter if they are coming from a console application, a WCF application, a script written in Python, a Fiddler composer -> they will all work or all fail with 404. So it appears that you are not making the same request from your WCF app.

Comment: Here's how you can enable tracing to be sure that you are looking at the correct HTTP request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Somehow my request going out of my WCF is blocked. I can not see them  in Fiddler

Comment: That's normal, Fiddler can only capture requests that go through it. Fiddler is just a proxy that registers to listen on port 8080. So unless you specify a proxy to your HttpClient it won't appear in fiddler. That's the reason why I pointed you in my previous comment a way to enable tracing and see the exact HTTP request being sent regardless of whether you are using a console or WCF application. If you prefer Fiddler then make sure that you have specified it as a proxy when making the request.

Comment: It was the message string, not the WCF issue, tracing helped a lot.Thank you!